# Mock kotlin function as parameter in Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, lambda, kotlin, mockito

I need to test a Kotlin function that accepts another function as parameter.
The class looks something like this:

```
class MyClass(val myInstance: MyObject) {

    fun toBeTested(text: String, number: Int) {
        myInstance.doSomething(text, otherFunction(number))
        ...
    }
}
```

My test so far looks like this

```
@Test
fun testFunction() {
    val mockInstance = mock(MyObject::class.java)

    myClass.toBeTested("test", 15)
}
```

I want to use a `verify(mockInstance, times(1)).doSomething()` but I need to specify inside the `doSomething` the parameters it takes, and I don't know how to specify the function.

Is it the right direction? Or should I take another way (maybe reorganising code or doing some other magic)?

many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Mockito.any()` requires a `Class<T>` as a first parameter, so what you want to do is get the `Class` instance of `() -> Unit`. 
Kotlin does not allow you to write `(() -> Unit)::class.java`, but it *does* allow you to access the underlying class of `() -> Unit`: `Function0`.

So to get the `Class<() -> Unit>` you need, you can do the following:

```
val f : Class<() -> Unit> = Function0::class.java as Class<Function0<Unit>>
```

You can pass this class to the `any` call:

```
verify(mockInstance, times(1)).doSomething(any(f))
```

---

Now this isn't very pretty, so you can define a custom `any()` function that does all this magic for you:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> myAny() = Mockito.any(T::class.java)
```

This lets you do the following:

```
verify(mockInstance, times(1)).doSomething(myAny<() -> Unit>())
// or:
verify(mockInstance, times(1)).doSomething(myAny())
```

This is what [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/1.x/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockito_kotlin/Mockito.kt#L44) does for you under the hood.

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm the author of mockito-kotlin

Comment: Hey @nhaarman, thank you for the reply. I actually followed your work and tried to implement it already (bug thanks for what you did for the community btw). The problem is that when I do that the test fails with the line "myAny<String>() must not be null" because my `doSomething` function accepts non-nullable parameters

Comment: If you look at the [file](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/1.x/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockito_kotlin/Mockito.kt#L44) I mentioned, you will see another 'hack', namely casting `null` to `T` using a `createInstance()` method.

Comment: Yes I checked it, but then the `createInstance` needs a `nonNullProvider` which in turns needs a `NullCaster` and `InstanceCreator` etc. which needs many more classes OR to import your library :)
And I was trying to see if there was a quicker way around it

Comment: Actually even importing your library and using its 'hack' with the `createInstance` the problem still remains and the test fails with `Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull`

Comment: `doSomething` needs to be open. Note that you can use the easy method mockito-kotlin2 will use: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/2.x/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockitokotlin2/internal/CreateInstance.kt

Comment: Once again thank you very much, the `open` made the trick (I had it on the class not the function itself) well suggested... darn those intricate and obscure errors :P